# Codeigniter Arabic language and rtl (right to left) stylesheet

Tags: codeigniter

I have a bilingual site, English and Arabic. Default language is Arabic and default loaded style.css is rtl. I switch the language with session and the translated text from language folder works correctly.

But for the second language (English) I have some issues:

1. When I am in About page and I switch language is goes to main page . How I can redirect to same page where I've been before switching language.
   My function to switch language is:

   ```
   public function change($type){
     $this->session->set_userdata('lang', $type);
     redirect(base_url());
   }
   ```
2. After switching the language I need that also the stle.css for English language gets loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to send the user to the same page between languages, you need to check which page the user is browsing, before invoking your function `change($type)`
You can get the current link like this:

```
$current_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

the redirect depends how your multi-language site is designed. It could be:

```
yoursite.com/ar
yoursite.com/en
```

or

```
en.yoursite.com
ar.yoursite.com
```

anyway basically you'll need to replace `en` with `ar`

the css change is easy to perform, just make use of the session you have created just before the redirect:

in the view file where you load the css, load the version depending on the session value of `lang`, make sure you use the default css, in case there is no session set (yet).